# Creating array of JSONs from php

Tags: php, ajax, json, extjs4.2, jsobject

**I am having trouble creating correct format of JSON to pass it to js from php.**
 
I am using `extjs` and in my `tree`, I need to add `children`:

```
var treePanel = Ext.create('Ext.tree.Panel',
{
    id: 'tree-panel',
    region: 'north',
    split: true,
    height: '50%',     
    minSize: 150,
    rootVisible: false,
    autoScroll: true,
    store: store,
    listeners: {// more code here}
});
```

Now I need to assign the create **`store`** variable:

```
var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.TreeStore', 
{
    root: 
    {
        expanded: false,
        children: file_names
    }
});
```

Now the problem appears when I have to create **`file_names`** object from within `php` tags.

- If I have `file_names = [{text: 'google', leaf: true, icon: 'pic.png'}, {text: 'yahoo', leaf: true, icon: 'pic.png'}]`, then everything is fine
- When I try to create this `file_names`'s content from within php, then I am starting to experience issues

This is how I am trying to create file_name from php:

```
var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.TreeStore', 
{ 
    root: 
    {
        expanded: false,
        children: [ 
                  <?php
                        $name      = empty($_GET['name']) ? false : $_GET['name'];
                        $files     = empty($_GET['files']) ? false : $_GET['files'];

                        if ($name)
                        {
                        //    $files_arr = explode(',', $files);    
                            $file_arr = array('text'=>$files_arr[0], 'leaf'=>true, 'icon'=>'images/xml.png');

                            //echo stripslashes(json_encode($file_arr));
                            echo json_encode($file_arr );
                         }
                    ?>
                    ]
    } 
};
```

Comment: Did you try json_encode?

Comment: Did you look at my code? It is there, I did try json_encode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way:

```
<?php
$name      = empty($_GET['name']) ? false : $_GET['name'];
$files     = empty($_GET['files']) ? false : $_GET['files'];

if ($name)
{
    $files_arr = explode(',', $files);    

    foreach ($files_arr as $value)
    {
        $file_arr[] = array(
        'text' => $value, 
        'leaf' => true, 
        'icon' => 'images/xml.png'
        );
    }       
}

$var = json_encode($file_arr);
echo $var;
```

Test:

```
http://localhost/test.php?name=test&files=google,yahoo
```

Give us:

```
'[{"text":"google","leaf":true,"icon":"images\\/xml.png"},{"text":" yahoo","leaf":true,"icon":"images\\/xml.png"}]'
```

---

And to output do it like this:

```
root: 
{
    expanded: false,
    children: <?php echo $var; ?>
}
```

ie: remove *['* and *']*, **json_encode** takes care of all needed to properly format javascript code.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid its `echo json_encode($file_arr );` not `echo json_encode(file_arr );`

Comment: That was a mistake here, not in my actual code; otherwise it would not compile